# Aspose.Cells - Opening OpenXml file generated by EPPlus

Tags: openxml, epplus, aspose-cells

I generated an Excel spreadsheets in OpenXml format using EPPlus. When I try to open it using Aspose.Cells, the program returns the following error:

Aspose.Cells.CellsException: ‘Invalid cell name’

I believe the cells didn’t find the correct file format.

How can I open this file?

I am using C# and .NET Core

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am Ahsan Iqbal from Aspose.

I have tested this issue with my own sample code but this issue is not reproduced.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating XLSX file using EPPlus");
    CreateExcelFileInEpplus();
    Console.WriteLine("Success in creating XLSX file using EPPlus");
    ReadExcelFileUsingAsposeCells();
    Console.WriteLine("Success in reading XLSX file using EPPlus");
}
static void CreateExcelFileInEpplus()
{
    var newFile = new FileInfo("output.xlsx");
    if (File.Exists(newFile.Name))
        File.Delete(newFile.Name);
    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        // do work here                            
        xlPackage.Save();
    }
}
static void ReadExcelFileUsingAsposeCells()
{
    Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook("output.xlsx");
    Console.WriteLine(workbook.Worksheets[0].Name);
}
```

This test shows that Aspose.Cells can read the Excel spreadsheet generated by EPPlus. Your sample code and output files are required for analysis. You may please create a thread at [Aspose.Cells Forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells) and share your code, output XLSX file, version of Aspose.Cells and .NET Core, operating system and other specific environment information if any. Our support team will assist you further in this regard.